# Como posso setar um valor em uma variável especifica em uma função com atributos opcionais?

Tags: php

Fiz o seguinte código para exemplificar o meu problema:

```
function teste($valor1 = '', $valor2 = ''){
    echo "Valor1: " . $valor1;
    echo "</br>";
    echo "Valor2: " . $valor2;  
}
```

Uma função bem simples, se eu fizer isso:

```
teste('aqui', 'aqui tambem');
```

O resultado será:

> ```
> Valor1: aqui
> Valor2: aqui tambem
> ```

Até ai tudo bem, mas o que eu preciso é enviar o valor somente para o segundo atributo, tentei da seguinte forma:

```
teste($valor2 = 'Aqui');
```

Mas o resultado foi este:

> ```
> Valor1: Aqui
> Valor2:
> ```

Utilizando python por exemplo eu consigo definir em qual atributo a valor será setado desta forma, colocando o nome da variável e atribuindo o valor na função, mas em php não funciona desta forma.

Como posso setar um valor em uma variável especifica em uma função com atributos opcionais?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tem muitas maneiras, depende do efeito desejado.

O normal é você por sempre as opcionais à direita, justamente para poder omitir:

```
function foo($requerido, $opcional = 12)
{
   ...
}
```

Mas se o comportamento padrão não serve, pode fazer algo assim:

```
function foo($opcional1, $opcional2 = 12)
{
    if ($opcional1 === null) $opcional1 = 25;
}
```

Ou mesmo, em PHP 7+:

```
function foo($opcional1, $opcional2 = 12)
{
    $opcional1 = $opcional1 ?? 25;
}
```

Aí você passa um nulo ao chamar, para usar o valor *default*:

```
foo( null, 27 );
```

(ou outro valor "mágico" que você eleja como *default*)

Note que esta construção também serve para resolver outro problema, que é a necessidade de valores não constantes (imagine se o *default* for `time()`, por exemplo - neste caso não pode ser atribuido no `function` de qualquer maneira, por não ser constante)

## Funções variádicas

Outra maneira é usar as funções variádicas, introduzidas no PHP5.6:

```
function minhavariadica(...$argumentos) {
  if( count( $argumentos ) == 2 ) {
    $opcional1 = $argumentos[0];
    $opcional2 = $argumentos[1];
  } else {
    $opcional2 = $argumentos[0];
  }
}
```

## Array associativo ou objeto

Se realmente tiver um número muito variável de parâmetros, talvez o melhor seja usar uma estrutura, evitando os parâmetros posicionais completamente:

```
$estrutura['nome'] = 'José';
$estrutura['idade'] = 12;
$estrutura['sangue'] = TYPE_O_POSITIVE;

processadados($estrutura);

function processadados($e) {
    $nome = isset($e['nome']?$e['nome']:'desconhecido'; // $e['nome']??'desconhecido' PHP7+
    $idade = ...

    ... mesma coisa para cada dado, ou usa literalmente no código...
```

A vantagem neste caso é que as coisas já entram na função com seu devido nome no índice, tornando a "conversão" em nova variável um passo opcional.